# Installing SSL Certificate on Nginx now website is not accessible

Tags: server, bash, 22.04, nginx, certificates

I'm having a heck of a time getting Ubuntu 22.04, Nginx and Certbot to play nicely together.

I'm a newb when it comes to Ubuntu so I'm learning my way with trial and error, though I seem to be getting a lot of the latter at this point.

Fresh install on a public virtual machine. I have installed all three applications. I had the site pointing to my domain and working but when I added the Certbox, all $#@& broke loose.  Now I cannot access my site at all, with or without https.

Ok, so I'll use "notmydomain.com" for my example.

I installed Certbot and followed the directions on their website and tried to start Nginx.

```bash
systemctl start nginx.service
```

I get this message:

```bash
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details.
```

So, I did just that and it gave me this:

```bash
# systemctl status nginx.service

× nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-10-30 09:17:39 CDT; 5s ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 535771 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 12ms
        
systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
nginx[535771]: nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/notmydomain.com/privkey.pem": PEM_read>
systemd[1]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

I checked the directory where the pem files reside:

```bash
# ls -l
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  44 Oct 28 03:00 cert.pem -> ../../archive/notmydomain.com/cert1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  45 Oct 28 03:00 chain.pem -> ../../archive/notmydomain.com/chain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  49 Oct 28 03:00 fullchain.pem -> ../../notmydomain.com/fullchain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  47 Oct 28 03:00 privkey.pem -> ../../archive/notmydomain.com/privkey1.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 692 Oct 28 03:00 README
```

I noticed that all of these files are owned by root. Should that be owned by another user so that Nginx can get access to them? Is that my problem? Who should own these files so they are accessible?

I checked the firewall permission to make sure I hadn't blocked myself out:

```bash
# ufw status numbered

Status: active
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
[ 2] 443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 5] Nginx HTTPS                ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 6] 443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 7] 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 8] Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 9] Nginx HTTPS (v6)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I have reissued the certificate to make sure there wasn't something wrong with it, I got no errors during this command:

```bash
# certbot certonly --standalone --domain notmydomain.com

Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Requesting a certificate for notmydomain.com

Successfully received certificate.
Certificate is saved at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/notmydomain.com-0001/fullchain.pem
Key is saved at:         /etc/letsencrypt/live/notmydomain.com-0001/privkey.pem
This certificate expires on 2024-01-28.
These files will be updated when the certificate renews.
Certbot has set up a scheduled task to automatically renew this certificate in the background.
```

I can provide more info if need, just not sure where to look next. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: NORMALLY this means that it can't access the certificate key.  This is the error we care about: `/etc/letsencrypt/live/notmydomain.com/privkey.pem`  This does **not match** what the renewal system says you have which is a completely different file path.  Are you **sure** you entered the correct paths, since CertBot says your paths should be `/etc/letsencrypt/live/notmydomain.com-0001/...` and not what's in your config?

Comment: Tyvm for the response!!! `This does not match what the renewal system says you have which is a completely different file path`  <-- Which path are you referring to that isn't correct?

Comment: literally said the path that's failing.  The path that's failing in NGINX is `/etc/letsencrypt/live/notmydomain.com/privkey.pem` for the key.  The paths that Certbot are giving you are `/etc/letsencrypt/live/notmydomain.com-0001/fullchain.pem` and `/etc/letsencrypt/live/notmydomain.com-0001/privkey.pem`.  These two don't match, so I'm pretty sure you're *not* referring to the right paths in your NGINX configs.

Comment: Thank you! Odd, I didn't enter that information in to the config. That was put there by the installation. I did change that but now I'm getting a conflict with the port being open. Thanks for the assist!